# What Are the Requirements for the Tenacious and Unsung Hero Badges?

Tags: discussion, badges

Nobody has gotten the following badges, and nobody ever will:

[`Tenacious`](/help/badges/50/tenacious) Zero score accepted answers: more than 5 and 20% of total.
[`Unsung Hero`](/help/badges/51/unsung-hero)Zero score accepted answers: more than 10 and 25% of total.

But that being said, I'm still a little curious what the requirements are for these?

What does 'more than 5 and 20% of total' mean? Does it literally mean that *at least 20% of your accepted answers need to have **no upvotes or downvotes?*** (or rather, the net score needs to equal zero)

Answer (score 1):

Your answers may have upvotes and downvotes, but those must balance out.

Those badges are awarded through a job that runs daily. You must meet the criteria for those badges when the job runs.

And yes, you must have more than five answers, and 20% or more of them to have been accepted a net balance of 0 score to get the Tenacious badge. Likewise, 11+ answers and 20%+ of them accepted to get Unsung Hero.

Those have never been obtained here due to the village nature of Worldbuilding (compared to the huge metropolis that is Stack Overflow, for example). Everybody here sees every question and answer that is posted, so you'll hardly ever have an answer that is both accepted and zeroed out.

Comment: Even I don't see *every* question, and I make a reasonable attempt to do so.

Answer (score 0):

It's awkwardly worded but appears to mean that, numerically, you'd need six or more accepted answers that themselves have either no votes or perhaps perfectly split +/- and that those six or more must be twenty percent and possibly more of the total.

It is totally opaque to me how one actually ears the badge: do I earn it by writing what amounts to lousy responses --- lousy enough that no one, not even the querent bothers to upvote?  Or is it by writing lousy queries?

These badges seem utterly useless, contrary to human nature and forum-antithetical to me.

Comment: You gain them as consolation prizes for the cases when you reply, are marked as correct, but the OP is too clueless to upvote and no one else cares.